# Chip Enable not setting at right moment using SPI

Tags: c, stm32, spi, hal, radio-transmission

Am trying to set a Chip Enable (CE) of a pin to go high before a SPI transfer and go back low upon accomplishing of the transfer (either TX or RX). Am using the NRF24L01 and Nucleo-F303. It is said that when the CE is high, thats when i can do a real SPI transfer to the NRF24L01. However, the CE pin goes momentarily low and then high again even before the real transfer hasnt been accomplished

[image]

The rest of the pins seem to be synching accordingly. How do i get the CE pin to exactly go high prior to making a SPI transfer and then Low when am done or not doing any more transfers.

Here is how i've attempted to solve the problem

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_SPI1_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();

    HAL_Delay(5);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    uint8_t data[6] = {0x5C, 0xBA, 0xBB, 0x4D, 0x5E, 0xFB,};
    uint8_t data1[6] = {0};

    while (1)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);

        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, data, data1, 6, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK)
        {
            HAL_Delay(1);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how i have configured GPIO_PIN_3 to function

```
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP; // digital Output
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going bare-metal because the libraries were giving a lot of delay and had so many abstract layers

Comment: And it is the right decision if your code does not have to be run on different models of the STM32 uCs

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Slave Select signal of SPI is active low but you can change this behaviour through bit SSIOP (it is the name of the bit on STM32H7 , might be different on other STM32).

About your other question, the Slave Select signal going inactive between two bytes, you can change that behaviour thanks to bit SSOM.

The different SPI configurations are usually pretty well described in the Reference Manual.